# How to prevent an event if there is an error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, bootstrap-modal

I've a dropdown list of cars. If any them goes inactive an error message is shown. When the error message is shown, if I click on the Route Car button event should be prevented. i.e no modal popup should be shown.

How to achieve this ?

Inactive cars are saab, ferrari, jaguar. When you select these inactive message will be shown.

**HTML**

```
<select id="drp">
    <option value="0">--SELECT--</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="jaguar">Jaguar</option>
</select>

<div class="divInactive">
    <span id="spninactive_Saab" style="display:none;">Saab is inactive</span>
    <span id="spninactive_Ferrari" style="display:none;">Ferrari is inactive</span>
    <span id="spninactive_Jaguar" style="display:none;">Jaguar is inactive</span>
</div>


<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Route Car" data-toggle="modal" href="~/Car/GetMethod?CarId=@Model.GeneralInfo.CarID" data-target="#divCarPopUp" />

<div id="divCarPopUp" role="dialog" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#drp").on("change", function() {
        var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
        $(".divInactive span").hide();
        $("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
    })
});
```

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/u6f3gxnc/)</kbd>

Comment: if there is an error pop up should not appear?

Comment: How do they go inactive? Seems like disabling or removing the option should be done then also. Then it's a simple matter of seeing if select has a value or not

Comment: @charlietfl I've implemented inactive error message.Don't need to worry about that.Provided you the example list.Just I don't need to show the popup if any inactive error message is shown.

Comment: *"Provided you the example list"* . just sounds like you came here expecting others to do your work for you. This isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `data-toggle="modal",data-target` attr from the button.So it will not open the modal by default.Open the modal using `click function` of the button and inside the function check which type of car is selected active or inactive

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var inactiveCar = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#drp").on("change", function () {
        inactiveCar = false;
        var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
        $(".divInactive span").hide();
        $("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
        if ($("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).length > 0) {
            inactiveCar = true; //inactive car found
        }
    })
});

$("#modalButton").on("click", function () {
    if (inactiveCar == false) { //inactive car is not selected so open popup
        $("#divCarPopUp").modal('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

[FIDDLER](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqnd8L6/3/)

Comment: check the fiddle i've given

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button if the selected item is inactive using the following.

```
$("#drp").on("change", function() {
  var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
  $(".divInactive span").hide();
  if ($("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).length) {
    $("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
    $('input[value="Route Car"]').prop('disabled', true);
  } else
    $('input[value="Route Car"]').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

See [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u6f3gxnc/1/).

Comment: i don't want to disable the button,popup should not appear on click of button.

Comment: @Hazard then what is supposed to happen...user clicks button and nothing happens? That's a not very user friendly interface

Comment: that's the requirement :)

Comment: @Hazard You should go discuss the requirements. I can't see any reason not to change the requirements for a better user experience + simpler implementation less prone to bugs

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the button when an inactive option is selec

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#drp").on("change", function() {
    var ddlTxt = $("#drp option:selected").text();
    $(".divInactive span").hide();
    $("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).show();
    if($("#spninactive_" + ddlTxt).length>0)
      $("input[value='Route Car']").attr("data-target","")
    else
      $("input[value='Route Car']").attr("data-target","#divCarPopUp")
})});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mjv0wscL/)

Comment: I don't want to disable the button.

Comment: If u dont want to disable it then change the data-target prop like this

https://jsfiddle.net/mjv0wscL/